# Evaluating values in a linear equation with 2 variables given by the user

Tags: ti-basic, ti-nspire

I'm trying to make a TI-Basic script for my "TI-nspire CX II CAS" that evaluates linear equations with 2 variables.

**This is my code:**

```
Define LibPub test()=
Prgm
 request "Insert function: ",fxy
 request "Point X: ",a
 request "Point Y: ",b

 Define p1(x,y)=fxy
 result:= p1(a,b)

 disp "The value is: ",result
 clearAz
EndPrgm
```

If I run this script with the following data:
`fx=x+y` `a=1` and `b=2`

**The output I'm getting is:**

> res=x+y

**The expected output / What I need is:**

> res=3

---

P.S.:

I noticed that removing the first `request` and typing an equation directly in the code (in the `define`) makes the code work as intended:

```
Define LibPub test()=
Prgm
 request "Point X: ",a
 request "Point Y: ",b

 Define p1(x,y)=x+y
 result:= p1(a,b)

 disp "The value is: ",result
 clearAz
EndPrgm
```

Input: `a=1` and `b=2`. Output:`res=3`

**But it is essential that the script evaluates the function and values given by the user.**

Any ideas of how to fix this code?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the pipe operator `|`, we can pass in specific values to an **expression**. This is often used to circumvent the need to write a **function** to pass in values.

```
Define LibPub test()=
Prgm
 request "Insert function: ",fxy
 request "Point X: ",a
 request "Point Y: ",b

 result:= fxy|x=a and y=b

 disp "The value is: ",result
 clearAz
EndPrgm
```